# WinCC, подлючить SQL через C-script,

Tags: c, winapi, tia-portal

Всем привет. Как **подключиться к SQL напрямую или через ОДБЦ из С-script** (не VB) в WinCC (TIA portal) или кто знает (у кого есть) **хелп по DB.H** в WinCC. Кто знает поделитесь опытом тк я только столкнулся с этой технологией в целом. Перелопатил кучу доков в просторах сети, но ничего толкового по данному вопросу не нашел, можно-то написать на VB, но хотелось бы на Си (он мне был как родной когда-то)
Заранее благодарен за ответ.

Answer (score -2):

Как обычно всем спасибо, за ответы и помощь оказанную в решении серьезной проблемы. Решение как всегда нашел сам, правильно или нет не знаю, зато - работает!!!
**РЕШЕНИЕ:** решением данного вопроса явилось написание собственной библиотеки для работы с БД, что также позволило обойти ODBC и работать с БД напрямую. Код либы не выложу, тк сильно благодарен всем за помощь...